# How to Combine Aggregate + Lookup and Search in Laravel

Tags: laravel, search, aggregate, lookup

I Have the following Aggregate + Lookup Query

Aggregate + lookup Query

```
$collection = Dapil_Kotakab::raw(function ($collection) use ($page, $perPage) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'as' => 'KecDetails',
                    'from' => 'src_kecamatan',
                    'foreignField' => 'id',
                    'localField' => 'idKecamatan'
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'as' => 'KotDetails',
                    'from' => 'src_kota_kabupaten',
                    'foreignField' => 'code',
                    'localField' => 'idKota'
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'as' => 'ProvDetails',
                    'from' => 'src_provinsi',
                    'foreignField' => 'idProv',
                    'localField' => 'idProvinsi'
                ]
            ],
            ['$skip' => ($page - 1) * $perPage],
            ['$limit' => $perPage],
        ]);
    });
```

And I have the following $Search code.

```
$collection = Dapil_Kotakab::whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=>  "\"".$word."\"" )))->skip(($page - 1)*$perPage)->limit($perPage)->get();
```

I have tried several times, But I keep getting error.

> Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.